# How to properly join results of multiple async methods?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, asynchronous, parallel-processing

In Silverlight app I need to run multiple async calls in parallel - they will call server to check data, etc. My pseudo-code-setup looks like this

```
public interface IAsyncVerifier
{
    event EventHandler OnCompleted;

    void Verify();
}

// Subscribe to verifier completion events
foreach (var verifier in this.VerifierEngine.GetVerifiers())
{
    var asyncVerifier = verifier as IAsyncVerifier;
    if (asyncVerifier == null || !asyncVerifier.IsVerifierRunning()) continue;

    asyncVerifier.OnCompleted += (s, a) => DoWhat(); // ????????
    asyncVerifier.Verify();
}
```

So, in my mind I have interface common for all those tasks. Then before execution I subscribe to all of their events and ... ?

I need to somehow wait for them to complete and proceed with what I'm doing. How to write remaining code properly? I see some kind of `counter` that I increment every time I call `Verify()` and decrement every time I get `OnCompleted`. But I don't get whole picture on how to wrap it together so it doesn't smell. Also, Silverlight runs those on background threads if I understand correctly (calls to WCF services)

EDIT:

I'm working with 3rd party verification engine. `this.Verifier.VerifierEngine` is not something I wrote. I can only add verifiers to collection. Usually they execute on main thread to validate properties, etc. My need is to create verifier that makes call back to server, hence `async` in Silverlight. I'm not dealing with threads manually, when I make call to service it returns on main thread so it's fine, this part hidden from me. All I want is to be able to "wait" until all of the verifiers completed. The only way I can check right now is the way I'm doing.

Therefore my UI is quirky. User hits' save after done modifying field and my verification starts. I check if all verifiers `IsVerifierRunning` and give user message that he needs to retry. I really need to be able to wait up for all to complete and then proceed.

1. I don't need to worry about threads unless proper solution will involve working with threads
2. I have access to results already

Comment: Can you add some more detail?  Calls to verify are already non blocking?  Or you need to make them non blocking?  Do you need access to results from verify?  Or simply notification/continuation when all verification is complete?

Comment: Also, is your verification loop already off the UI thread?  If you want to use any sort of blocking synchronization (such as a manual reset event as noted by other answer'ers) you need to be sure that you are not on the ui thread.

Comment: Do you mean to convey like this example?: " 2 async calls are made. when both the calls get completed, you want to proceed further"

Comment: Any chance you could have the server run the methods synchronously and then return a single result?  It would make it much simpler.

Comment: We use ORM for this and don't have any performance problems so far. Making "bundles" like this will be a maintenance issue in a long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too suggest using the Reactive Framework (Rx) to do what you want.

First up you need a function that will turn `IAsyncVerifier` into an observable that will kick off the verification process and subscribe to the `OnCompleted`. Here it is:

```
Func<IAsyncVerifier, IObservable<Unit>> startVerifier = av =>
    Observable.Create<Unit>(o =>
    {
        var subject = new AsyncSubject<Unit>();
        var s1 =
            Observable
                .FromEventPattern(
                    h => av.OnCompleted += h,
                    h => av.OnCompleted -= h)
                .Select(_ => Unit.Default)
                .Subscribe(subject);
        var s2 = subject.Subscribe(o);
        av.Verify();
        return new CompositeDisposable(s1, s2);
    });
```

This function uses an `AsyncSubject` to make sure that it captures the event firing.

Now the query becomes quite straight forward.

```
var query = (
    from av in VerifierEngine
        .GetVerifiers()
        .OfType<IAsyncVerifier>()
        .ToObservable()
    where !av.IsVerifierRunning()
    from result in startVerifier(av)
    select av)
        .ToArray();
```

In the Rx world, since this is a `SelectMany` query the default is to run these on the thread pool - so it is run in parallel.

The final `.ToArray()` call is a little different to the enumerable version of the function. The observable version changes an `IObservable<T>` (an observable that returns zero or more values) into `IObservable<T[]>` (an observable that returns a single array of zero or more values). In other words, this will wait until all of the verifiers are finished before returning them all.

Now you just have to subscribe to the query and run whatever code you want to knowing that all the verifiers have completed.

```
query.Subscribe(avs => DoWhat());
```

If you want to run some code each time a verifier finishes **and** when all of them finish then you can take off the `.ToArray()` call and subscribe to the query like so:

```
query.Subscribe(av => { /* Each */ }, () => { /* All */ });
```

I hope this is all clear enough.

Comment: Is Rx part of SL 5 or I need to package it? I really do want to learn rx, right now it's like a magic also I looked at it many times in a past. Hard to wrap my head around. I have to admit code looks very sharp...

Comment: @katit - I'm not sure what version of Rx is in SL5 - or if it's there, but the DLL is fairly small so it shouldn't be too much of a burden. And yes, you should learn Rx - it's bloody awesome and it will help make a lot of async operations nice and sharp (as you put it). :-)

Answer (score 3):

I use Linq to Rx 
using System.Reactive.Linq;
Observable.FromEvent
  Zip the method

```
  var InitNetCellCache = InitNetCell();
            InitNetCellCache.Subscribe((s) =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("init NetCell Cache OK.");

                //ScheduleCrrentThread(innerAction);
            });
            var InitKPIMapCache = InitKPIMapCell();
            var zipped = InitKPIMapCache.Zip(InitNetCellCache, (left, right) => left + " - " + right);

            zipped.Subscribe((s) =>
                {
                    //When all async methods are completed
                    runtime.Show();
                }
            );

  IObservable<object> InitNetCell()
    {
        IUnityContainer unityContainer = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IUnityContainer>();
        INetCellManager inc = unityContainer.Resolve<INetCellManager>();
        var NetCell = Observable.FromEvent<InitCacheCompletedDelegate, object>(
         h => ((object sendera) => h.Invoke(sendera)),
         h => inc.InitCacheCompleted += h,
         h => inc.InitCacheCompleted -= h);
         //Run you async method
        inc.InitCache();
        return from e in NetCell select e;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I've heard about your requirements, I think a simple counter is sufficient.  For now, I'm going with the solution that is closest to what you posted and listing the assumptions that need to be valid in order for it to work.  If any assumptions are invalid, let me know and I'll update the code appropriately.

If your loop is running on the UI thread it can be as follows.  There are several assumptions in here.  First is that we are on the UI thread and the calls to verify execute on the ui thread.  This puts the DispatcherSynchronizationContext into effect.  Completion events from wcf will execute in the same SynchronizationContext that they began in.  This will effectively serialize their execution which will give your code a very single threaded behavior, so locking/etc isn't necessary on the counter.  Some more on that here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8chs7ft(v=vs.95).aspx .  Second assumption is that the verify calls will always complete, even if they error.

Edited to match unsubscribe requirement.  Bear with any typo's as I just used notepad for this.  EventHandler may have to be a specific type of event handler depending on your event args.

```
int activeVerifiers = 0;
List<VerificationCleanup> cleanups = new List<VerificationCleanup>();

EventHandler completionHandler = (s, a) => 
{
     activeVerifiers--;
     if(activeVerifiers == 0)
     {
          //execute some sort of message/notification/all complete event

          foreach(VerificationCleanup cleanup in cleanups)
          {
            cleanup.Cleanup();
          }
     }
}; 

foreach (var verifier in this.VerifierEngine.GetVerifiers())
{
    var asyncVerifier = verifier as IAsyncVerifier;
    if (asyncVerifier == null || !asyncVerifier.IsVerifierRunning()) continue;

    cleanups.Add(new VerificationCleanup(completionHandler, asyncVerifier));

    activeVerifiers++;
    asyncVerifier.OnCompleted += completionHandler
    asyncVerifier.Verify();
}

private class VerificationCleanup
{
    private EventHandler eventHandler = null;
    private IAsyncVerifier verifier = null;

    public VerificationCleanup(EventHandler eventHandler, IAsyncVerifier verifier)
    {
        this.eventHandler = eventHandler;
        this.verifier = verifier;
    }

    public void Cleanup()
    {
        if(this.verifier != null)
        {
            this.verifier.OnCompleted -= this.eventHandler;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: All assumptions is correct and it is almost working with one "but". There should be some code to unsubscribe from events. How do I do that? Right now with anonymous delegate if I put debug.trace inside I see how every time routine called I get number of OnCompleted doubeld

Comment: Edited to deal with un wireup

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight does have the [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), which would give you what you need. However, the code would need to look different than what you have.

Is there a particular reason that you wouldn't want to use a counter and a spin loop? It isn't as pretty, but it also wouldn't require as many code changes as other approaches.

Erick

Comment: How do I do spin loop? It might be ugly but will work and work reliably for what I need. Code in question is just a prototype so I can refactor as I need... Last time I did spin loops were like 6 years ago with VB6 DoEvents() :) I don't think silverlight has DoEvents functionality.

Comment: If you have a counter that increments for each work item, then have a statement like while (counter >0) Thread.Sleep(500)